# docker-in-docker with gitlab and dind not working

Tags: docker, gitlab

I'm trying to create a pipeline using docker in docker with the docker executer.
My gitlab is running on a virtual machien, and my build server(gitlab-runner) is hosted on another virtual machien.

I have found tons of information on the possible causes, but for some reason none, seem to be working or doesn't fit my problem.

my yamls file:

```
image: docker:23.0.1

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
    - when: always

services:
    - name: docker:23.0.1-dind
      alias: docker


variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2  

stages:
  - build
  - test  
  - cleanup

include:
  # Static
  - template: Jobs/Container-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml
  - template: Jobs/Dependency-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml
  - template: Jobs/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml
  - template: Jobs/Secret-Detection.gitlab-ci.yml 
  - template: Jobs/Code-Quality.gitlab-ci.yml

# Start Application Build and Test
build-XRecorder:
  stage: build
  variables:
    IMAGE: technologyresearcher/test:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
  before_script:
    - docker login -u technologyresearcher -p $Registery_Password
  script:
    - docker build -t $IMAGE .
    - docker push $IMAGE

test-XRecorder:
    stage: test

    script:
        - dotnet test

# Start Security Scanner Configurations
semgrep-sast:
  variables:
    SAST_EXPERIMENTAL_FEATURES: "true"
    SCAN_KUBERNETES_MANIFESTS: "false"
    SAST_EXCLUDED_PATHS: ".gitlab, chart, docs, network-policies, scripts, terraform, tests"
  cache: {}


secret_detection:
  variables:
    SECRET_DETECTION_EXCLUDED_PATHS: "docs, tests, scripts, network-policies, terraform"
    GIT_DEPTH: 100

code_quality:
  rules:
    - if: $CODE_QUALITY_DISABLED
      when: never
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

code_quality_html:
  extends: code_quality
  variables:
    REPORT_FORMAT: html
  artifacts:
    paths: [gl-code-quality-report.html]
# End Security Scanner Configurations
```

testes scenarios:

using docker:latrest and dind:lates and tested with same version specific container, for docker -dind tested with and without alias.

for the tcp ulr I have tried, localhost, localip, docker

when I try to use docker as url/domain name, I get the error that it doesn't find the docker domain name, when I try to use localip I get i/o timeout and localhost I get 'is the docker daemon running'

Any idea, what might be the problem, is there anything else I can try?

EDIT:

to answer som eof the questions here is a minimal example of the pipeline:

```
image: docker:latest

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
    - when: always

services:
    - name: docker:dind
      alias: docker


variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2  

stages:
  - build
  - test  
  - cleanup

# Start Application Build and Test
build-XRecorder:
  stage: build
  variables:
    IMAGE: technologyresearcher/test:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
  before_script:
    - docker login -u technologyresearcher -p $Registery_Password
  script:
    - docker build -t $IMAGE .
    - docker push $IMAGE

test-XRecorder:
    stage: test

    script:
        - dotnet test
```

so yes gitlab-runner has access to docker, becuase I have set it in the correct group
yes docker is running on the same virtual machine as gitlab-runner tested with docker info

I have the same problem:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker-in-docker with gitlab and dind not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77423901/docker-in-docker-with-gitlab-and-dind-not-working)

Comment: So what is the problem? What error are you getting? Please post the exact full verbatim copied in text error message that you are getting. ` I get the error that it doesn't find the docker domain` From who? Where? What is "it"? Do you run docker deamon in the virtual box running gitlab-runner? Does gitlab-runner user has access to docker deamon on that box? What does the gitlab-runner logs say? `and tested` What did you exactly "test"? What was the result? Finally, why specify `docker:dind` service globally for all SAST etc. containers? They don't use it, only build-Xrecorder uses docker

Comment: Are all the other `include:` and jobs in posted `.gitlab-ci.yml` relevant for the problem at hand? Please create a minimal [MCVE] . Does a simple small job that uses docker:dind service and runs `docker info` works?